# How manually mimic the bullet in the itemize environment?

Tags: tables, itemize

I have created the following `tabularx` environment (using the package `tabularx`, of course) to serve as a specialized bulleted list for a resume.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r \p{3in} X r}
    $\bullet$ & This is some experience & & startdate--enddate
\end{tabularx}
```

I would've preferred to use the Itemize environment, but I could not figure out how to get the multiple columns for the date. While the bullet produced is not bad, it does not match the spacing used in the `itemize` environment. Is there a way that I can consistently mimic the spacing used by `itemize` to make my `tabularx` environment match?

**EDIT:** As DavideCarlisle mentions in his answer, and I alluded to in my comment, I am using `tabularx` for the column X that will give me flexible white space. Using the primitive `\extracolsep`, I can rewrite my example with `tabular*` in the following way.

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{r \p{3in} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r }
    $\bullet$ & This is some experience & startdate--enddate
\end{tabular*}
```

I mention this to emphasize that my question is really about the placement of the bullet rather than the rest of the table's configuration. I do want to say, however, that I appreciate everyone's more general feedback.

Comment: Posible duplícate of [How to create columns within an itemize environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72701/how-to-create-columns-within-an-itemize-environment)

Comment: what text are you putting in the X column? In your fragment it is empty. X is an expensive thing to use on empty columns:-)

Comment: It's probabably better to use a list rather than a table as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72701/how-to-create-columns-within-an-itemize-environment/72778#72778

Comment: I am using the X column as a rough equivalent to `\hfill` for this purpose. @DavidCarlisle, I will definitely implement one of these solutions. I created this particular `tabularx` as quick and dirty fix to the question that you cited.

Comment: @Fran, you are correct that this post was inspired by my attempts to answer the question that you cited. However, this question is of interest to me independent of the solution to the cited question, because I believe that it'd be useful to understand how to generate spacing that matches a standard list environment, such as `itemize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicate in comments that you just want stretchy glue before the last column. There is no need to get LaTeX to fake this with an `X` column. Adding stretch glue between columns is a primitive feature of the underlying `\halign` primitive and available in teh core latex format using `tabular*` `tabularx` is an attempt to copy the syntax of `tabular*` but modify column widths rather than inter-column space, it is *far* less efficient that `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    $\bullet$ & This is some experience &  startdate--enddate\\
    $\bullet$ & This is another experience &  startdate--enddate
\end{tabular*}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test text
\item Test text
\end{itemize}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}>{$\bullet$\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    This is some experience &  startdate--enddate\\
    This is another experience &  startdate--enddate
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Or more accurately copying the list layout, with an example with 0pt parindent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Test text
\item Test text
\end{itemize}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\labelwidth}\llap{\labelitemi}\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    This is some experience &  startdate--enddate\\[\itemsep]
    This is another experience &  startdate--enddate
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your second example, and I have a problem. In the document class that I am using (res.cls) the value of \parindent is 0in, but my lists are still being indented somewhat, so they do not match in my case. I have tried to determine where this value is stored, but I cannot find it. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

The following example shows two possibilities; in the second one, the bullets are added automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in}@{}X  r}
    $\bullet$ & This is some experience & & startdate--enddate\\
    $\bullet$ & This is another experience & & startdate--enddate
\end{tabularx}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test text
\item Test text
\end{itemize}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}>{$\bullet$\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in} X r}
    This is some experience & & startdate--enddate\\
    This is another experience & & startdate--enddate
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Werner** mentions in a comment, by setting `\arraystretch` conveniently,  the separation between rows in `tabularx` matches the separation between items in the standard `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in}@{}X  r}
    $\bullet$ & This is some experience & & startdate--enddate\\
    $\bullet$ & This is another experience & & startdate--enddate
\end{tabularx}
}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test text
\item Test text
\end{itemize}
{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}>{$\bullet$\hspace{\labelsep}}p{3in} X r}
    This is some experience & & startdate--enddate\\
    This is another experience & & startdate--enddate
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Other than trial and error, how would I find the right value for `\arraystretch`?

Comment: @CarlMorris I need to do some calculations but right now I am too tired. In some hours I'll let you know what I've found.